# How to use a PreferenceFragment in a FragmentPagerAdapter (android.support.v4)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

In my `MainActivity`, I am using a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`. I have seen many questions like this one, except the answers say to use `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`, which is now deprecated. What is the current, proper, up-to-date answer of how to include a `android.preference.PreferenceFragment` inside a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Note: My minimum sdk version is 16.
Note 2: I'd prefer to use only android/google provided libraries, if possible.

I have no idea if this is possible, but can the `PreferenceFragment` be shown inside an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to combat this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) as an alternative to `PreferenceFragment` that works with the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` as discussed in [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T)

It is part of the [v7 Preference Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v7-preference).

Comment: A note to anyone else seeing this question:
You may see the v14 support library provides some preference related stuff, but the `PreferenceFragment` provided there is based on `android.app.Fragment`, so it wont work with the support v4 stuff